# Javascript split function not correct worked with specific regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem. I have a string - `"\,str\,i,ing"` and i need to split by comma before which not have slash. For my string - `["\,str\,i", "ing"]`. I'm use next regex

```
myString.split("[^\],", 2)
```

but it's doesn't worked.

Comment: You realize the second argument `2` is limiting the number of splits to `2`? What is the output of `myString.split("[^\],", 2)` now?

Comment: Try `myString.split(/[^\],/g)`, `"[^\],"` is a string not a regular expression.

Comment: Actually, I don't think you can use split for this, since it will consume the non-backslash character before the string and Javascript regexes don't support lookbacks.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse a line of CSV with RegEx, but JS doesn't have the ability to do lookbehinds.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is ridiculous to avoid the lack of lookbehind but seems to get the correct result.

```
"\\,str\\,i,ing".split('').reverse().join('').split(/,(?=[^\\])/).map(function(a){
    return a.split('').reverse().join('');
}).reverse();

//=> ["\,str\,i", "ing"]
```

Comment: Uh, this looks even more complicated than mine :-) But cool idea to use lookahead, +1

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your expected output but you are specifying string not a regex, use:

```
var arr = "\,str\,i,ing".split(/[^\\],/, 2);
console.log(arr);
```

To `split` using regex, wrap your regex in `/..../`

Comment: This will remove the character before the comma as well.

Comment: @kennebec: Well as I have said in my answer, not sure about expected output but have pointed out the way to use regex in conjunction with `split`

Answer (score 0):

This is not easily possible with js, because it does not support lookbehind. Even if you'd use a real regex, it would eat the last character:

```
> "xyz\\,xyz,xyz".split(/[^\\],/, 2)
["xyz\\,xy", "xyz"]
```

If you don't want the `z` to be eaten, I'd suggest:

```
var str = "....";
return str.split(",").reduce(function(res, part) {
    var l = res.length;
    if (l && res[l-1].substr(-1) == "\\" || l<2)
//      ^                        ^^          ^
//  not the first         was escaped      limit
        res[l-1] += ","+part;
    else
        res.push(part);
    return;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines, it looks like you want to split a string by `,` characters that are not preceded by `\` characters.

It would be really great if JavaScript had a regular expression lookbehind (and negative lookbehind) pattern, but unfortunately it does not. What it *does* have is a lookahead (`(?=)` )and negative lookahead (`(?!)`) pattern. Make sure to [review the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

You can use these as a lookbehind if you reverse the string:

```
var str,
    reverseStr,
    arr,
    reverseArr;
//don't forget to escape your backslashes
str = '\\,str\\,i,ing';

//reverse your string
reverseStr = str.split('').reverse().join('');

//split the array on `,`s that aren't followed by `\`
reverseArr = reverseStr.split(/,(?!\\)/);

//reverse the reversed array, and reverse each string in the array
arr = reverseArr.reverse().map(function (val) {
    return val.split('').reverse().join('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You picked a tough character to match- a forward slash preceding a comma is apt to disappear while you pass it around in a string, since '\,'==','...

```
var s= 'My dog, the one with two \\, blue \\,eyes, is asleep.';
var a= [], M, rx=/(\\?),/g;
while((M= rx.exec(s))!= null){
    if(M[1]) continue;
    a.push(s.substring(0, rx.lastIndex-1));
    s= s.substring(rx.lastIndex);
    rx.lastIndex= 0;
};
a.push(s);


/*  returned value: (Array)
My dog 
the one with two \, blue \,eyes 
is asleep.
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Find something which will not be present in your original string, say `"@@@"`. Replace `"\\,"` with it. Split the resulting string by `","`. Replace `"@@@"` back with `"\\,"`.

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var s1 = "\\,str\\,i,ing";
   var s2 = s1.replace(/\\,/g,"@@@");
   console.log(s2);
   var s3 = s2.split(",");
   for (var i=0;i<s3.length;i++)
   {
       s3[i] = s3[i].replace(/@@@/g,"\\,");
   }
   console.log(s3);
 </script>
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zr45J/)